# How to mount a shared directory in linux

Tags: networking, filesystems, samba, mount

RaspberryPi
Samba Server
Share directory: jack
**Host Computer
Mount (read/write access): jack directory from RaspberryPi**

I have this task , its a connection between my RPI and my host computer , I have a samba server running on my rpi with the shared directory jack . Can someone explain mounting to me and how it can be done in this case

Answer (score 1):

Hum, not really clear.

- Is your Pi the Samba server with a directory to share on it ?
- What is your client ? A Windows client ? A Linux client, workstation or headless ?
- Do you want a public share ? Or with an auth (user + password) ?

For a Linux client, you can mount a public CIFS (Samba) folder with :

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/jack
sudo mount -t cifs //your.samba.server.ip/jack /mnt/jack
```

Or with an authentification

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/jack
sudo mount -t cifs //your.samba.server.ip/jack /mnt/jack -o rw,username=toto,password=secret
```

More info in `man mount`.

Don't forget to install correct packages on your client :

`sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`